# How to modify CSS code to have one accordion panel open at start?

Tags: html, css, accordion

Ok, I have the following code that works great.  I just need to modify it so that there is a default panel that is open when it loads/refreshes.

```
#acc-label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 330px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;

  -moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#320BB8', endColorstr='#320078');
  background:-webkit-gradient( linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.05, #320BB8), color-stop(1, #320078) );
  background:-moz-linear-gradient( right center, #320BB8 5%, #320078 100% );
  background-color:#320BB8;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#321D85;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:15px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:-1px -1px 0px #3227B0;
  text-align: center;
  font: 14px/50px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; 

  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
}

#rad2 + label {
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#320BB8', endColorstr='#320078');
  background:-webkit-gradient( linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.05, #320BB8), color-stop(1, #320078) );
  background:-moz-linear-gradient( right center, #320BB8 5%, #320078 100% );
  background-color:#320BB8;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#321D85;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:15px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:-1px -1px 0px #3227B0;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease, background 0.5s ease;
}

label:hover, #rad2 + label:hover {
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#320078', endColorstr='#320BB8');
  background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05,         #320078), color-stop(1, #320BB8) );
  background:-moz-linear-gradient( top center, #320078 5%, #320BB8 100% );
  background-color:#9B0629;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*SLIDES*/
.accslide {
  display: block;
  height: 330px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;

 color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  font: 12px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;

  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.accslide p, h2, img {
  width: 420px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.accslide img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .accslide {
  width: 450px;
}
```

The accordion works great.  I just don't know what to add in to make the first panel be the default one opened when the page loads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u make a fiddle please?

Comment: I'll try, never did one before. one sec.

Comment: try including html as well

Comment: Err....seems this is more complicated that I thought.  This code is being used on a wordpress test site, so it's not like I can just copy/paste or even just write up a simplified version.

Comment: Just a note: if you dont know how many tabs you have and which one of them you want to open first you'd have to use JavaScript to select the first available element as "active".

Comment: Surprisingly it was easier than thought.  It is actually built into the setup using an options for buttons:

checked="checked"

Added that to the first slide (or any other element you wanted) and done!

Thanks for all your help guys!  Learning more and more each day!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, without any reference I'm pretty much guessing, but you could accomplish it through something like:

If it has a class, such as `first`

```
.accordian-slide:nth-child(1) /* or :first-child */ {
   display: block; /* or whichever you're using */
}
.accordian-slide {
   display: none;
}
```

Or if it's using something like `.opened`/`.closed` classes added to slides

```
.opened { 
   display: block;
}
.closed {
   display: none;
}
```

Otherwise, if there's a config file maybe you can set the default opened pane?

Comment: Hmm, food for thought.  Thanks.  I'll play with it and see what I can break :)